# How to trigger CallBackQueryHandler returned by the user with a regex pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, telegram, telebot

I am creating a bot that has dynamic buttons and want to detect if the start of the callback query is `classes_` and then allow me to further parse. How would I use regex or a built in pattern function to detect the beginning of a string?

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: c.data == f'classes_'.startswith)
def callback_is_return(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    print('Found!')
```

I tried using `().startswith`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: c.data.startswith('classes_'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.